# ignore records that exists in two tables sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

table 1

```
ID    Department     Category
555       16           test
888       16           test
0001      16           test
```

table 2

```
ID  Department     Date
555    67         2015-04-28
111    58         2015-04-28
000    45         2015-04-28
```

how do i create a stored procedure if i had to pass in the parameter value table1.department=16 it must retreive all the records from table1 but  if the id is in table 2 it must ignore that record.

expected output if i pass parameter table1.department=16

output

```
ID    DEpartment       Category
888     16               test
0001    16               test
```

id 555 should get ignored.

what was attempted

```
select *
from table1 as t1 inner join table2 as t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID
where t1.department='16'
```

Comment: you need to try **t1.ID != t2.ID** or **t1.ID <> t2.ID** instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will return your desired Result,

```
SELECT Table1.ID, 
        Table1.Dept,
        Table1.Category 
FROM table1 WHERE Table1.ID NOT IN (SELECT Table2.ID FROM table2)
```

Comment: the inner join returns all records that match,i want to ignore that record,i did try this attempt at first but it retrieves the id 555

Comment: I have placed <> in join, Did you see that?

Comment: @doe "<>" it does mean that It will return only those records which ID(s) are not same.

Comment: sorry i didnt notice,i tried that now but its retreiving all multiple records